# get JSON not being imported by Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I am having trouble with loading JSON into an app that im creating

```
  $("#load_basic").click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/show.php',
    method: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      $("#textarea").html(json.doc);
    }
  });
});
```

My JSON from show.php is as follows

```
{
"id": "1",
"title": "doc 1",
"doc": "Lorem Ipsum",
"lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:33:49"
} {
"id": "3",
"title": "doc 2",
"doc": "another lorem ipsum document",
"lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:39:31"
}
```

Please can anyone help. Firstly I was attempting to do it locally and I thought this might be the problem but now Ive tried it live on the server and still no joy. Any ideas?

This is the show.php source for creating the JSON file

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
include 'db.php';
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM docs';
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die('<p class="db_error"><b>A fatal MySQL error    occurred while trying to select <b>EVERYTHING</b> from the database.</b><br />Query: '.$query.'<br />Error: ('.mysql_errno().') '.mysql_error().'</p>');

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      $arr = array('id'=>$row['id'],'title'=>$row['title'],'doc'=>$row['doc'],'lastsaved'=>$lastsaved = $row['lastsaved']);
        echo json_encode($arr);
 }//end while
?>
```

Comment: what output do you get? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: No, I dont get any error in the console or any output at all

Comment: If this is really your JSON string, then you have a problem : it is not valid JSON : if you want a list of items, then you should have an array, and the items should be separated by commas.

Comment: To eliminate the fact your JSON is invalid as suggested you could create a php array and then use json_encode to return a valid JSON string

Comment: keep adding the rows to $arr using $arr[] = array(... and then only call json_encode() once instead of inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON which you have uploaded is not valid JSON. What I think you have expected is array of JSON, looking like following.

```
[{
"id": "1",
"title": "doc 1",
"doc": "Lorem Ipsum",
"lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:33:49"
}, {
"id": "3",
"title": "doc 2",
"doc": "another lorem ipsum document",
"lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:39:31"
}]
```

Notice existence of square brackets and commas. To get output like this, use `json_encode()` on array of objects (or associative arrays, depending on what you're using), instead of echoing every separately. For example instead of:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $arr = array('id'=>$row['id'],'title'=>$row['title'],'doc'=>$row['doc'],'lastsaved'=>$lastsaved = $row['lastsaved']);
    echo json_encode($arr);
}//end while
```

Do:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $arr[] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'title'=>$row['title'],'doc'=>$row['doc'],'lastsaved'=>$lastsaved = $row['lastsaved']);
}//end while
echo json_encode($arr);
```

If you have a lot of data which might not fit into memory as single array, you can try:

1. echo `[` character
2. For every object you want to parse:

   1. echo `,` character unless it's first object
   2. echo JSON for your object
3. echo `]` character

Comment: Hi, ive added the source for my php file (above) I have done an array and json_encode it. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong in my PHP file as I think this is where the problem lies.

Comment: Aaron Lumsden: I can see `mysql_fetch_array()`. As I have said, you're echoing every object separately instead of uploading array of objects to JSON. Just read the solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid JSON. You're missing the comma between the objects.

```
...
"lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:33:49"
} {
 ^ Missing comma
```

You probably want to send an array of objects, and refer to `json[0].doc`, such as:

```
[{ ... },  { ... }]
```

or just send a single object, and refer to `json.doc`:

```
{
"id": "1",
"title": "doc 1",
"doc": "Lorem Ipsum",
"lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:33:49"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning two objects, they need to be in an array.

Your JSON needs to be:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "doc 1",
        "doc": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:33:49"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "doc 2",
        "doc": "another lorem ipsum document",
        "lastsaved": "2012-02-12 08:39:31"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your code here:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    $arr = array('id'=>$row['id'],'title'=>$row['title'],'doc'=>$row['doc'],'lastsaved'=>$lastsaved = $row['lastsaved']);
        echo json_encode($arr);
}//end while
?>
```

Should become

```
<?php

$json_output = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    $json_output[] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'title'=>$row['title'],'doc'=>$row['doc'],'lastsaved'=>$lastsaved = $row['lastsaved']);

}//end while

echo json_encode($json_output);
?>
```